# How to dynamically create a 2d vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, data-structures, c++14

`vector< vector<int>> arr(n);`
arr is a 2d vector. I want to take input "columns" from user and then the elements.

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int cols; cin>>cols;
        
        //Statements
    }
```

How shall I create the cols sized vector inside that **for loop**?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the size of each vector inside the vector with `cols`? If so, you can probably just do `arr[i] = vector<int>(cols);` for each.

Comment: You need two nested loops. Think a bit about it. It is not that hard.

Comment: [The `std::vector` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) have many overloads, including one taking a *value* as the second argument after the size. You can provide another vector object with the column size there.

Comment: Thanks a lot mediocrevegetable1 zdf and  Some programmer dude. I did it.

Comment: @Chapo144 Could also post your solution (answer your own question) ? It might  be useful for anyone else that comes across this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it like this.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //rows=5 and columns are dynamically initialized
    vector<vector<int>> v(5);
    int cols;
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        cout<<"Enter column count for row : "<<i+1<<"\n";
        cin>>cols;
        v[i]=vector<int>(cols);
        cout<<"Enter Data";
        for(int j=0;j<cols;++j)
            cin>>v[i][j];
    }
    cout<<"your data was :-\n";
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<v[i].size();++j)
            cout<<v[i][j]<<"  ";
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vector< vector> a(M, vector (N));
just declare column before , then insert values to rows.
or you can use array of vector.
vector v[5];

Answer (score 0):

First just take the column size. then create the vector and then take the input;

```
int col,num;
cin >> col;

vector<vector<int>> arr(n,vector<int>(col));   
// this creates a vector of size n, whose elements are in turn vectors of size col

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;i<col;j++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        arr[i][j]=num;
    }
}
```